# How do I create an S3 lifecycle policy that moves everything to intelligent tiering and maintains a single previous version for a window of X days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out the exact S3 bucket lifecycle rules I need for my use case. I think I've got it right but my testing has been inconclusive - from AWS's docs it looks like there is an undefined lag between when a rule *should* have been applied and when it actually is. All that they guarantee is that the billing will reflect the defined rules. I also find the wording in their docs and in the S3 UI confusing and ambiguous.

The configuration I want is this:

- all files and versions to be placed in Intelligent Tiering ASAP
- in addition to the current version, maintain ONE previous version
- ... but delete that previous version after 90 days

I'm setting policies via the ruby SDK as follows:

```
  s3.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
    bucket: 'my-awesome-bucket',
    lifecycle_configuration: {
      rules: [
        {
          id: 'my-awesome-policy',
          prefix: '',
          status: 'Enabled',
          transitions: [
            {
              storage_class: 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING',
              days: 0
            }
          ],
          noncurrent_version_transitions: [
            {
              storage_class: 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING',
              noncurrent_days: 0
            }
          ],
          noncurrent_version_expiration: {
            noncurrent_days: 90
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    }
  )
```

Is this correct? I'm aware that there are similar questions out there, but the options here have subtly changed in recent years and I want to be absolutely sure I've got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing your s3 lifecycle policies, you have keep in mind the following:

- Minimum Days for Transition from S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA

This means that before you can move any of your objects, you must store them at least 30 days in the S3 Standard storage class.

- The 0 days rule is not as ASAP as you might think.

This rule means that the objects are eligible for transition at midnight UTC following creation *and* the minimum storage time (see the previous point).

- S3 Lifecycle configurations supports keeping 1 to 100 versions of any object.

A versioning-enabled bucket has one current version and zero or more noncurrent versions for each object. So, in your case, you'd use something like this:

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        ...
        <NoncurrentVersionExpiration>     
            <NewerNoncurrentVersions>1</NewerNoncurrentVersions>
            <NoncurrentDays>90</NoncurrentDays>    
        </NoncurrentVersionExpiration>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Hope this helps you understand the s3 lifecycle policy rules and validate yours, taking into the consideration the constraints.